# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "junto a" y "junto con"?

Tags: preposiciones

El contexto es el siguiente: una persona hizo una investigación sobre la violencia en una región del país y colectó los datos necesarios en una institución que sirve como una base de datos acerca de ese problema. En ese contexto, ¿cuál de las dos opciones es la más adecuada?

"Fueron colectados los datos junto a la institución x"

o

"Fueron colectados los datos junto con la institución x"

Gracias!

Comment: Sería mejor *junto con personal [colegas] de la institución x.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En este contexto ambas opciones son correctas, es decir: ambas están perfectamente bien gramaticalmente. Sin embargo, la primera (donde se utiliza *junto a*) es ambigua, porque *junto a* significa dos cosas:

1. "acompañado por, con la ayuda de"
2. "(físicamente) al lado de"

Si dices *junto a la institución X*, algunas personas podrían entender que los datos fueron reunidos y depositados en un lugar físico (un edificio con archivos, por ejemplo) situado a un lado del edificio de la institución X.

En cambio la opción con *junto con* no es ambigua: *junto con* significa "acompañado por, con la ayuda o colaboración de" y sólo eso. A mi oído además es un poco más formal y va mejor con esta idea. Por lo tanto yo usaría *junto con*, o cambiaría la expresión para hacer explícita la idea, diciendo *con la ayuda de la institución X*.